# How to sort a Hashmap by key String?

Tags: java, string, sorting, date, hashmap

I am using some holiday dates in a HashMap.

```
this.holidayMap.put("01.05", new Event("1. Mai"));
this.holidayMap.put("14.02", new Event("Valentinseday"));
```

That is some of my input. I have a separate method to add them. Now I want to sort them by the String - Date but I have no clue how to do it. I have seen many post of simple Strings but mine are a bit difficult because of the date format.

I just want to call a method which then sorts the HashMap.
I don't want to change the HashMap in a other type. Because I must use a HashMap.

I am sorry I have no code to present.

Best Regards

Comment: You don't sort a hashmap - they're unordered (or rather, the ordering isn't specified, and can change).

Comment: Are you looking for the implementation of a method along the lines of `List<Event> getEventsOrderedByDate(Map<String, Event> events)`?

Comment: You can't sort a `HashMap`. You should use a [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) equipped with a specialized `Comparator`.

Comment: Handling dates and sorting maps have been addressed many times on Stack Overflow. Always search thoroughly before posting.

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems with this. I can solve one, but not the other precisely to your requirements as stated.

The easy one is how to sort the strings as date values. The solution is to use the built-in `MonthDay` class. This has a natural ordering from January 1 through December 31. It’s straightforward to parse your strings into `MonthDay` objects.

The part I cannot do is sort a `HashMap`. You cannot control the order of the entries in a `HashMap`. Suggestions include:

- Take out all the data from the `HashMap` into a list (or array) and sort it.
- Use a `SortedMap`, typically a `TreeMap` as Thomas Fritsch suggested in a comment
- The closest I can get: Use a `LinkedHashMap`. You can control the order as either the insertion order or the access order. To sort the map, you need to sort the keys and then for each key in turn either remove it and reinsert, or just query its mapped value. `LinkedHashMap` is a subclass of `HashMap`, so it does count as one. Though this may give you what you asked for, it sounds a bit absurd in my ears.

Just for illustration and aware that it conflicts with what you asked, here’s a way to convert you `HashMap<String, Event>` to a `TreeMap<MonthDay, Evenet>` using streams:

```
    DateTimeFormatter parseFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM");
    SortedMap<MonthDay, Event> sortedHolidayMap = this.holidayMap
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap((Map.Entry<String, Event> e) -> MonthDay.parse(e.getKey(), parseFormatter), 
                                      (Map.Entry<String, Event> e) -> e.getValue(),
                                      (u, v) -> { throw new IllegalArgumentException(); },
                                      () -> new TreeMap<MonthDay, Event>()));
```

For a first test I tried filling a few more holidays into the `HashMap`:

```
    this.holidayMap.put("01.05", new Event("1. Mai"));
    this.holidayMap.put("14.02", new Event("Valentinesday"));
    this.holidayMap.put("03.10", new Event("Tag der deutschen Einheit"));
    this.holidayMap.put("01.01", new Event("New Year"));
    this.holidayMap.put("17.05", new Event("Grunnlovsdag"));
    this.holidayMap.put("17.03", new Event("St. Patrick"));
```

They come out nicely sorted:

```
01.01 New Year
14.02 Valentinesday
17.03 St. Patrick
01.05 1. Mai
17.05 Grunnlovsdag
03.10 Tag der deutschen Einheit
```

Answer (score 0):

---

If you have to use a HashMap you could put your keys in a Float list or vector and sort your keys and Keep your HashMap.

---

```
java.util.HashMap<String, Event> holidayMap = new java.util.HashMap<String, Event>();

holidayMap.put("01.05", new Event("1. Mai"));
holidayMap.put("14.02", new Event("Valentinseday");

java.util.Vector<Float> v = new java.util.Vector<Float>();

// Use an Iterator to loop through the HashMap and add it to the Vector
Iterator it = holidayMap.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();          
    v.add(Integer.valueOf((String) pair.getKey()));

}

// now all you have to do is sort your keys
BubbleSort s = new BubbleSort(v);
```

**Use your sorted keys in the list or Vector get sorted Map data on demand**
But I do suggest you use LinkedList or Binary Tree

Comment: There’s something I like about the idea. I would not use `float`s, though. I believe the strings are dates (without year becuase the same holidays occur every year), so `01.05` means May 1 and `14.02` means February 14. One may also prefer `ArrayList` and its own `sort` method (or `Collections.sort()`).

Comment: I did overlook the date thing and your solution makes more sense than mine.